# IndexedDB is not available in your browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-extensions

When using the add-on Tab Session Manager, an error stated `IndexedDB is not available in your browser`. I was able to use Tab Session Manager correctly until yesterday, but now I am having trouble with my saved tabs disappearing.

What should I do? I am running Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Firefox, as it is a known problem stated on the add-on's [Github page](https://github.com/sienori/Tab-Session-Manager/wiki/IndexedDB-Error), and it is one of the tags you added.

To try and fix:

> 1. Clear browser cache and cookies, and restart the browser and see if the problem persists.

> 2. Go to Settings -> Privacy & Security -> set History to "remember history" (or alternative "custom history" laid out in the Github.

If neither of the two above work, it can be due to a corrupted service file:

> 3a) Go to about:profiles -> open "root directory" of your current profile -> close Firefox browser.
>
> 3b) Cut "storage" and paste to a safe location -> open Firefox -> go to about:debugging -> scroll down to "tab session manager" and copy down the "internal uuid" -> close Firefox.
>
> 3c) Now, go to the storage folder you saved elsewhere, go to the "default" folder and copy the folder that says moz-extension+++(*tab session manager internal uuid you copied before* -> paste (overwriting the file now in the folder) into the same location in the root directory from step 3a.
>
> 3d) If you have other add-ons and services in the storage/default folder, you can copy and paste them in your root directory storage/default the same way as you did tab session manager.