# IndexedDB error

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser-addons

I'm using the Tab Session Manager extension.

I get an "IndexedDB is not available in your browser" message

All the tabs I have saved in the past have disappeared.

https://github.com/sienori/Tab-Session-Manager/wiki/IndexedDB-Error

I'm trying to fix it using the method described above, but I'm not sure what to do.

I'm using Edge as my browser.

Version 6.12.1 of Tab Session Manager

Version 6.12.1 of Tab Session Manager.

How can I restore it?

Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexedDB is not available in your browser](https://superuser.com/questions/1794714/indexeddb-is-not-available-in-your-browser)

Comment: Please use edit to add information to your existing question rather than post again.